# IE6 table width

Tags: html-table, css-float, width, internet-explorer-6

This document have some unexpected layout in IE6 (tests in IE tester.):

1. double margin between .receptacle's left edge and .albuminfo box left edge
2. table not adaptive width(in .albumvocal box)

Who can help solve problems? If you have another method that sets table have 100% width in .albumvocal box please tell me.

--------------------------------------original html---------------------------------------

```
<body>
<div id="receptacle">
<div class="albuminfo">
    <img alt="title" src="middle_special_329225.jpg" />
    <p>album info</p>
    <p>album info</p>
    <p>album info</p>
    <p>album info</p>
</div>
<div class="albumvocal">
<div style="width:100%">

    <h2>album name</h2>
    <table width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>vocal</th>
    <th>artist</th>
    <th>zone</th>
    <th>style</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>vocal1</td>
        <td>artist1</td>
        <td>zone1</td>
        <td>style1</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>vocal2</td>
        <td>artist2</td>
        <td>zone2</td>
        <td>style2</td>

    </tr>


    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="albumeaddinfo">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

----------------------------------------style---------------------------------------------

```
    #receptacle{
        width:958px;
        margin:0 auto;
        border:1px solid #F00;}
    .albuminfo img{
        width:190px;
        height:190px;}
    .albuminfo{
        text-align:center;
    float:left;
    padding:1.5em;
    margin:2em 0 0 1%;
    border:1px solid #00F;}
.albumvocal{
    margin:2em 0 1em 30%;
    padding:1em;
    border:1px solid #F0F;}
.albumeaddinfo{
    clear:both;}
table {
    height:1%;
    zoom:1;
    width:100%;
    border: solid 1px #e8eef4;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The double margin problem is almost certainly IE6's well known "Double Margin on floats" bug.

See here for a detailed discussion of the bug: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

This is a well known bug, you can work around it by maybe using `padding` instead of `margin`, or additional markup, but the page linked above also details a "fix" which should solve the problem:

Add `display:inline` to the styles for `.albuminfo`.

This is an IE6 hack, and is actually poor code in general because a floated element should not have a `display` property. But it will solve the bug in IE6, and shouldn't break your code in other browsers (but do test it to make sure!), because floated elements are always displayed as blocks so the `inline` style will be ignored.

The second problem with the table width I can't help with immediately (I don't have IE6 to hand on this machine, and I'm not going to install it just for this), but I note you have both CSS `width:100%` and the `width="100%"` attribute on the table. You shouldn't need both, even for IE6 and certainly not for any other browser; drop the attribute.

Finally, do you have a specific requirement to fully support IE6? If you do, then I feel very sorry for you. But if not, or if you can get away with a site that works but doesn't quite look perfect, then I would suggest ignoring these problems. Very few people are still using IE6, and those that are using it are well used to sites looking rubbish.